# python, struggling to plot CSV file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

as the title explains I'm trying to read in a CSV file and plot it, the file is in the following format:

```
Dishwasher,60,1,1,1,0,0,1

Washing Machine,200,0,0,0,0,1,1
```

where I just want to plot the 6 digits at the end.

Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
y1=[]
y2=[]

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
with open('File.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = [row for row in plots]
y1=int((rows[0])-2)
y2=int((rows[1])-2)

plt.plot(x,y1, label='Washing Machine')
plt.plot(x,y2, label='Dishwasher')
plt.show()
```

I've been trying to solve the problem for hours now but everything I do brings about a new error.

In this code, the error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Which from my understanding means it's trying to convert a list into an integer which isn't possible? Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in those 2 lines:

```
y1=int((rows[0])-2)
y2=int((rows[1])-2)
```

you are taking the first and second elements of the list subtracting 2 and transforming on an int the assigning it  to the variables `y1` and `y2` 
that means you cant subtract an int from a list

i recommend you to inspect your values before plotting it you can use the debugger or just print `rows`, `y1` and `y2` and you will have more insight on what is going on

the error tells you exactly what is going on:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

obs try this out:

```
y1=rows[0][2:]
y2=rows[1][2:]
```

Comment: Thank you, its working now but i still face the problem of excluding those first two elements in each row, how could i skip over them?

Answer (score 1):

First your rows is a list containing tuples, thus with rows[0] you refer to the first tuple not the integer inside. You have to go deeper to pick it.

Second you substract a string with an integer with this expression : `int((rows[0])-2)` (because you convert after substracting and not before)

Third, you must pass an iterable to the plot function which is x-length

so I just see you provide the csv, the script works with my csv rebuild file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
y1=[]
y2=[]

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
with open('File.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    rows = [row for row in plots]

y1=[int(row[0])-2 for row in rows]
y2=[int(row[1])-2 for row in rows]

plt.plot(x,y1, label='Washing Machine')
plt.plot(x,y2, label='Dishwasher')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rows is array of arrays. Rows[0] is array and you trying to do rows[0] - 2